# Javascript - Subtotal not adding cents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that is taking a product price and changing the line total onChange of the QTY input. Everything seems to work fine per line item, but the Subtotal and Total are not taking cents into account. Below is the function I have...

```
function updateOrder(id){
   var price = $("#qty_"+id).val()*$("#price_"+id).val();
$("#total_"+id).val(price.toFixed(2));

var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('totals'),
    result = document.getElementById('order_subtotal'),
    tresult = document.getElementById('order_total'),
    odiscount = document.getElementById('order_discount'),
    sum = 0;            

for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    var ip = inputs[i];

    if (ip.name && ip.name.indexOf("order_subtotal") < 0) {
        sum += parseInt(ip.value) || 0;
    }

}
result.value = sum.toFixed(2);
tresult.value = (result.value - odiscount.value).toFixed(2);    


}
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you could make a fiddle so that we could see this in action or maybe post some of the HTML as well?

Comment: looks to me this part is the problem ... `sum += parseInt(ip.value)` you're taking the int part

Comment: you have a parseInt. Any decimals will get stripped here

Comment: You are using parseInt() and need to use parseFloat() to get "cents"  (decimals).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`.

Comment: Knew it would be something small. Thank you for your quick response. And yes, that was the answer I was looking for.